# Spark SQL package not found

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am quite new to Spark, and have the following trouble: when I try to import SQLContext with:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
```

or try to initialize SQLContext variable explicitly:

```
SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
```

I get an error from Eclipse:

> The import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext cannot be resolved

I have put Spark into the dependency file, and everything else is fine except for the SQLContext. The whole code:

```
package main.java;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

public class SparkTests {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkMain");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

        //DataFrame df = sqlContext
        System.out.println("\n\n\nHello world!\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it with `mvn package`, I get the compilation error:

> package org.apache.spark.sql does not exist

Any ideas why the SQL package cannot be found?

**EDIT:**

The dependency file pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Simple Project</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use Spark SQL  or `DataFrames` in your project you'll have to add `spark-sql` artifact as a dependency. In this particular case:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId> <!-- matching Scala version -->
    <version>1.6.1</version>  <!-- matching Spark Core version -->
</dependency>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This is very helpful, even somehow the spark examples mentioned in official site is missing this dependency. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/examples/pom.xml

Comment: the large spark repo is broken up into smaller build artifacts: core, sql, catalyst, etc.